# How do you return from two functions deep in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

The setup is like this:

```
var blah = function () {
    var check = false;
    verify({ success: function () {
        if... check = true;
        else... check = false;
    }});
    return check;
};
```

The idea is to use the verify function to check something, and then return `true` or `false`. However, the method above will always return `false` — returning before the `success` function is called.

How do I get the results I need?

Comment: Why don't you just make `verify` return what you need: `var check = verify(...);`

Answer (score 2):

you cant,

```
var blah = function (callback) {
  verify({ 
    success: function () {
      if () { 
        callback(true);
      } else { 
        callback(false);
      }
     }
  });
};

blah(function(result) { 
  // my code here
});
```

Jquery 1.6 has a new promise api that allows you to take the return of an async call and make it look a little more synchronous, but its basically the same as this.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `verify` is calling the success function asynchronously?

If that is the case, what you need to do is package up what you are going to do after `blah` as a function - call it `foo`. Then within `verify` call into `foo` - for example:

```
    if...  { foo(true);  }
    else...{ foo(false); }
```

Answer (score 0):

For your example, you could do something like this:

```
var blah = function () {
    var check;
    try{
        verify({ success: function () {
            if... throw true;
            else... throw false;
        }});
    }
    catch(e){
        check = e;
    }
    return check;
}
```